# fluent-ffmpeg module: "end" event does not fire

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, stream, buffer, fluent-ffmpeg

**I'm using the [`fluent-ffmpeg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg) npm module**

I've POSTed a video from my client, and am using `new stream.Readable` to "read" the video Buffer.

ffmpeg is converting and saving the file, and everything seems beautiful, but the "end" event never fires.

My code is as follows:

```
const videoStream = new stream.Readable({
    read: function (n) {
        this.push(myVideoBuffer);
    }
});

ffmpeg(videoStream)
.on('progress', e => console.log(e))
.on('end', () => {
    console.log('ended')
    videoStream.destroy();
})
.on('error', e => console.error(e))
.save(`${process.cwd()}/media/videos/${Date.now()}.mp4`);
```

I get a log on every progress event, and it does save the video, but the "end" event's callback never gets called.

I assume this is a bug, since everything else works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, I had to push `null` to my Readable stream after I pushed my Buffer in order to end the stream, which ended the ffmpeg process in turn.

```
const videoStream = new stream.Readable({
    read: function (n) {
        this.push(myVideoBuffer);
        this.push(null);
    }
});
```

That's it; now my "end" event is firing, and all is well.